# Flask not detecting .css in static folder

Tags: python, css, flask

Here is my directory hierarchy

```
flaskApp
|_ flaskApp.py
|_static
|  |_realsurfstyle.css
|
|_templates
  |_Realsurfhtml.html
```

Here is the relevant `render_template` from the flaskApp.py file

```
@app.route('/<surfBreak>')
def waveHeight(surfBreak):
    return render_template("Realsurfhtml.html", name=surfBreak)
```

Here is my code from the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='static/realsurfstyle.css')}}"/>
```

I dont see what im missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to place static in the file path to the .css file. In essence you're telling it that path to the file is `/static/static/realsurfstyle.css` so instead try and write the path as `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='realsurfstyle.css')}}"`

Additionally, I would recommend placing the .css files in a folder in the static directory labeled css. which would change the file path to `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/realsurfstyle.css')}}"`